# Append to only one column in a dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an empty panda date frame. I want to append value to one column at a time. I am trying to iterate through the columns using for loop and append a value (5 for example). I wrote the code below but it does not work. any idea?

example:

```
  df: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    
        for  column in df: 
            df.append({column: 5}, ignore_index=True)
```

I want to implement this by iterating through the columns. the result should be

```
df: ['a', 'b', 'c']
      5    5    5
```

Comment: Do you want to append a row each time or a single column?

Comment: Pandas doesn't accommodate being used like this(!) Maybe describe what you want to do higher level, because pandas won't do exactly what you've asked.  Things that would work well: Adding whole columns at a time (not rows). Creating a new dataframe from a list of rows, each row a dict. Creating a new dataframe from a list of dataframes.

Comment: I am trying to fill data per columns,  once a whole columns is filed a move to the next. I do it per column because the data I am appending in the column is related to the columns string

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a horrible idea as it would become extremely inefficient as your df grows in size and I'm almost certain there is a much better way to do this if you would give more context.  But for sake of answering the question you could use the shape of the df to figure out the row, and the column name as the column and use `.at` to manually assign the value.

Here we assign 3 values to the df, one column at a time.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[],'b':[],'c':[]})

values_to_add = [3,4,5]

for v in values_to_add:
    row = df.shape[0]
    for column in df.columns: 
        df.at[row,column] = v
```

Output

```
     a    b    c
0  3.0  3.0  3.0
1  4.0  4.0  4.0
2  5.0  5.0  5.0
```